# Как сделать прокрутку простого окна tkinter python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я делаю программу расписания дел, и распределения обязанностей между персоналом. И вот всю логику я уже прописал, но осталась маленькая `проблема`, которую я уже 3-тий день не могу решить, это `прокрутка окна tkinter по горизонтали`.

Программа у меня большая, поэтому кординально менять в ней я ничего не хочу.

Мне нужно знать **как сделать работающий scroll по окну tkinter без canvas и прочих сильно меняющий программу библиотек и функций**. Вот код программы:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Эта программа создана для введения записей на фолте, для распределения объязанностей
сотрудников.
Эта программа крайне стабильна, использует язык программирование Python версии 3.7,
также технологии баз данных sqlite3, для работы на локальных устройствах.
применяется технологии ООП, для создание многочисеных объектов схожий между собой.
класс "instruments" является паттерном для обектов как one, tree, add.
"""

"""
таблица с датами под названием "dat":
эл.1  : O  = ответственный
эл.2  : S  = статус
эл.3  : N1 = наименование номер 1
эл.4  : N2 = наименование номер 2
эл.5  : T1 = требуемое количество штук 1 
эл.6  : T1 = требуемое количество штук 2
эл.7  : M1 = место хранение номер 1
эл.8  : M2 = место хранения номер 2 
эл.9  : I1  = индекс элемента 1
эл.10 : I2  = индекс элемента 2
"""

import sqlite3 as sq#импортирую библиотеку для работы с sqlite
from tkinter import *# импортирую библиотеку для окон


root = Tk()#создаю окно
root["bg"] = "#323661"
root.geometry("1200x800")#размером 1200x800
root.title("Пользовательское окно")

conn = sq.connect("info.db") #присоединяеюсь к локальной дазе данных
cursor = conn.cursor()#создаю элемент управления-редактирования базой данных
paste = [()]#создаю глобальную переменную вставки в базу данных
save_list = []#список полученных данных
save_list_data = []#список полученный данных для дат
index_last = 0#последний индекс элемента
index_height = 110#индекс размещания объектов
deleteTF = False#переменная отвечающая за удаление записей
one = None#пока пустой объект
i_data_day = 800


class instruments():# создаю класс на основе которого будет 
                    # создаватся интерфейс
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root #инициализация окна

    def send_button(self,btn_label,x,y,click=None,bg="#336882"):#функция добаления кнопок
        btn = Button(self.root,text=btn_label, bg=bg,font="Courier 8",command=click)
        btn.place(x=x, y=y)

    def send_label(self,labels,x,y):#функция добавления надписей
        self.lab = Label(self.root,text=labels,bg="#323661",fg="#FFFFFF",font="Courier 8")
        self.lab.place(x=x,y=y)

    def delete_label(self):#функция удаления надписей
        self.lab.grid_remove()

    def send_entry(self,x,y,width=20):#функция создания поля ввода
        self.entr = Entry(self.root,width=width,bg="#498AAB")
        self.entr.place(x=x,y=y)
    def save_entry(self):#функция возврата написанного в поле ввода
        return self.entr.get()
    def clear_entry(self):#функция очистки поля ввода
        self.entr.delete(0,END)

    def send_text(self,x,y,width=30,height=40):#функция добавления поля ввода для 
                                               #объемного текста
        self.text = Text(self.root,width=width,height=height,bg="#498AAB",font="Courier 8")
        self.text.place(x=x,y=y)

    def save_text(self):#функция получения данных из объемного поля ввода
        return self.text.get(1.0,END)

    def clear_text(self):#функция очиски поля ввода
        self.text.delete(1.0,END)

    def quit(self):#функция насильного закрытия окна
        self.root.destroy()

    def clear_window(self):#функция очистки окна от всех компонентов
        for w in self.root.winfo_children():
            w.destroy()

    def add_scroll(self,x,y,height,width=10,gor="vertical"):#функция добавленя ползунка на окно
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.root,orient=gor)
        self.scrollbar.place(x=x,y=y,height=height,width=width)

    def send_radio(self,list_names,x,start_y):
        self.Rbuttons = []
        self.var = IntVar(self.root)
        self.var.set(0)
        for BtnR in range(len(list_names)):
            Radiobutton(self.root,text=str(list_names[BtnR]),variable=self.var, value=BtnR, command=self.select_radio)\
            .place(x=x,y=start_y)
            start_y += 40

    def save_radio(self):
        return self.var_get

    def select_radio(self):
        print(self.var.get())
        self.var_get = self.var.get()


def add():#функция добавленя записей
    def Save():
        global save_list
        global index_last
        save_list.append(entry1.save_entry())#>
        save_list.append(entry2.save_entry()) #
        save_list.append(entry3.save_entry()) #собираю информацию со всех полей ввода
        save_list.append(entry4.save_text()) #>
        #инициализирую список содержащий вводную информацию
        paste = [(save_list[0],save_list[1],save_list[2],index_last,save_list[3])]
        SV = save_list
        #проверка на подлиность данных
        if len(SV[0]) > 0 and len(SV[1]) and len(SV[2]) > 0 and len(SV[3]) > 0:
            sql = "INSERT INTO OBVIinf VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
            cursor.executemany(sql,paste)
            sql = "INSERT INTO dat VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
            for elm in range(365):
                paste = (["None","None","None","None","None","None","None","None",index_last,elm,],)
                cursor.executemany(sql,paste)
            conn.commit()

            entry1.clear_entry()
            entry2.clear_entry()
            entry3.clear_entry()
            entry4.clear_text()
            save_list = []
            paste = [()]
        else:
            #и если данные не подленные
            tree.send_label("Информация `не заполнена!",60,450)
        #очищаем все вставки
        save_list = []
        paste = [()]
        index_last += 1
        update()

    #создание самого окна добавления
    root_add = Tk()
    root_add["bg"] = "#323661"
    root_add.geometry("700x500")
    root_add.title("Добавлене объекта")
    tree = instruments(root_add)
    entry1 = instruments(root_add)
    entry2 = instruments(root_add)
    entry3 = instruments(root_add)
    entry4 = instruments(root_add)
    entry1.send_entry(150,100,20)
    entry2.send_entry(150,150,20)
    entry3.send_entry(150,200,20)
    entry4.send_text(400,100,35,20)
    entry1.send_label("Оборудование:",20,100)
    entry2.send_label("Наименование:",20,150)
    entry3.send_label("Вид работы:",20,200)
    entry4.send_label("Информация",470,70)
    tree.send_button("Сохранить",60,400, lambda: Save())


def delete_btn():#функция перенаправления, помогающая удалить запись
    global deleteTF
    one.send_label("Кликните на объект который хотите удалить",500,770)
    deleteTF = True


def func_add(add_list,height,indexs):#функция сихронного заполнение окна данными
    index = 10
    for i in range(len(add_list)):
        one.send_button(add_list[i],index,height, lambda : open_inf(indexs))
        index += 250

def open_inf(index):#функция просмотра данных о объекте
    global deleteTF
    global update
    if deleteTF == True:
        sql = "DELETE FROM OBVIinf WHERE I = "+str(index)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
        sql = "DELETE FROM dat WHERE I1 ="+str(index)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
        deleteTF = False
        one.delete_label()
        update()
    else:
        sql = "SELECT * FROM OBVIinf WHERE I=?"
        cursor.execute(sql, [(index)])
        info = cursor.fetchall()
        root_info = Tk()
        root_info["bg"] = "#323661"
        root_info.title("Информация")
        root_info.geometry("500x500")
        four = instruments(root_info)
        four.send_label("Информация о объекте '"+str(info[0][0])+"':",10,10)
        four.send_label(info[0][4],10,50)


def update():#функция обновления данных
    global one
    global root
    global start
    global fulls
    global index_height
    index_height = 110
    one.clear_window()
    start()
    fulls()


def save_sql(otdel, cto, indexs, indexs2):
    global cursor
    global conn
    def_sql = "UPDATE dat SET "+otdel+" = '"+str(cto)+"'"+"\nWHERE I1 = "+str(indexs)+" AND I2 = "+str(indexs2)
    cursor.execute(def_sql)
    conn.commit()
def data_inf(indexs,indexs2):
    global save_list_data
    global save_sql
    add_data_root = Tk()
    add_data_root["bg"] = "#323661"
    add_data_root.geometry("1200x600")
    five = instruments(add_data_root)
    sql = "SELECT rowid, * FROM OBVIinf ORDER BY I"
    for row in cursor.execute(sql):
        if row[4] == indexs:
            element = row
            break
    five.send_label("Элемент:",10,10)
    five.send_label(element[1],70,10)
    five.send_label("Ответственный:",10,40)
    five.send_label("Статус:",10,80)
    five.send_radio(["запланирована","в работе","назначене","выполнена"],20,130)
    five.send_label("Необходимый инвентарь:", 10,300)
    five.send_label("Наименование:",10,320)
    five.send_label("Требуемое кол-во штук:",200,320)
    five.send_label("Место хранения:", 410,320)
    five.send_button("Сохранить",260,570,lambda: save_data())
    FE1 = instruments(add_data_root)
    FE2 = instruments(add_data_root)
    FE3 = instruments(add_data_root)
    FE4 = instruments(add_data_root)
    FE5 = instruments(add_data_root)
    FE6 = instruments(add_data_root)
    FE7 = instruments(add_data_root)
    FE1.send_entry(140,40,20)#ответственный
    FE2.send_entry(10,340,20)#наименование 1
    FE3.send_entry(10,360,20)#наименование 2
    FE4.send_entry(200,340,20)#требуемое кол-во штук 1
    FE5.send_entry(200,360,20)#требуемое кол-во штук 2
    FE6.send_entry(410,340,20)#место хранения 1
    FE7.send_entry(410,360,20)#место хранения 2
    sql = "SELECT rowid, * FROM dat ORDER BY I1"
    send_status = ""
    for row in cursor.execute(sql):
        if row[9] == indexs and row[10] == indexs2:
            five.send_label("ОТВЕТСТВЕННЫЙ:",900,20)
            five.send_label(row[1],1100,20)
            if row[2] == "0":
                send_status = "Запланирована"
            if row[2] == "1":
                send_status = "В работе"
            if row[2] == "2":
                send_status = "Назначена"
            if row[2] == "3":
                send_status = "Выполнена"
            five.send_label("СТАТУС:",900,50)
            five.send_label(send_status,1100,50)
            five.send_label("НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ №1",900,110)
            five.send_label(row[3],1100,110)
            five.send_label("НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ №2",900,140)
            five.send_label(row[4],1100,140)
            five.send_label("ТРЕБУЕМОЕ КОЛ-ВО ШТУК №1",900,170)
            five.send_label(row[5],1100,170)
            five.send_label("ТРЕБУЕМОЕ КОЛ-ВО ШТУК №2",900,200)
            five.send_label(row[6],1100,200)
            five.send_label("МЕСТО ХРАНЕНИЯ №1",900,230)
            five.send_label(row[7],1100,230)
            five.send_label("МЕСТО ХРАНЕНИЯ №2",900,260)
            five.send_label(row[8],1100,260)
    save_list_data = []
    def save_data():
        global save_list_data
        global save_sql
        save_list_data.append(FE1.save_entry())
        save_list_data.append(five.save_radio())
        save_list_data.append(FE2.save_entry())
        save_list_data.append(FE3.save_entry())
        save_list_data.append(FE4.save_entry())
        save_list_data.append(FE5.save_entry())
        save_list_data.append(FE6.save_entry())
        save_list_data.append(FE7.save_entry())
        sql = "SELECT rowid, * FROM dat ORDER BY I1"
        for row in cursor.execute(sql):
            if row[9] == indexs and row[10] == indexs2:
                element_data = row
                break
        save_sql("O",save_list_data[0],indexs,indexs2)
        save_sql("S",save_list_data[1],indexs,indexs2)
        save_sql("N1",save_list_data[2],indexs,indexs2)
        save_sql("N2",save_list_data[3],indexs,indexs2)
        save_sql("T1",save_list_data[4],indexs,indexs2)
        save_sql("T2",save_list_data[5],indexs,indexs2)
        save_sql("M1",save_list_data[6],indexs,indexs2)
        save_sql("M2",save_list_data[7],indexs,indexs2)

        paste = ([save_list_data[0],str(save_list_data[1]),save_list_data[2],save_list_data[3],
                  save_list_data[4],save_list_data[5],save_list_data[6],save_list_data[7],indexs,indexs2,],)


def fulls_data(indexs,indexs2,height,i_data_day,color_bg):
    if color_bg == "0":
        back_color = "#3216B0"
    elif color_bg == "1":
        back_color = "#FC0107"
    elif color_bg == "2":
        back_color = "#FECE01"
    elif color_bg == "3":
        back_color = "#1DD201"
    else:
        back_color = "#FFFFFF"

    one.send_button("  ", i_data_day, height, lambda : data_inf(indexs,indexs2),back_color)
    i_data_day += 50


def start():#функция стандартного заполнения окна компонентами
    global one
    one = instruments(root)
    one.send_label("Оборудование",10,60)
    one.send_label("Наименование",260,60)
    one.send_label("Вид работы",470,60)
    one.send_button("Добавить",10,10,lambda: add())
    one.send_button("Обновить",80,10,lambda: update())
    one.send_button("Удалить",150,10,lambda: delete_btn())
    one.add_scroll(10,790,10,800+(365*50),"horizontal")

    one.send_label("Пон", 800,10)
    one.send_label("Втор", 850,10)
    one.send_label("Сред", 900,10)
    one.send_label("Чет", 950,10)
    one.send_label("Пятн", 1000,10)
    one.send_label("Суб", 1050,10)
    one.send_label("Вос", 1100,10)

start()

def fulls():#функция заполнения-присваивания индексов элементам
    global one
    global index_last
    global index_height
    global fulls_data
    global i_data_day
    i_data_day = 800
    sql = "SELECT rowid, * FROM OBVIinf ORDER BY I"
    for row in cursor.execute(sql):
        func_add([row[1],row[2],row[3]],index_height,row[4])
        index_last = row[0]
        index_height += 50

    sql = "SELECT rowid, * FROM dat ORDER BY I1"
    index_height = 110                            
    week = 0                                       
    for row in cursor.execute(sql):
        fulls_data(row[9],row[10],index_height,i_data_day,row[2])
        i_data_day += 50                                  
        week += 1                                       
        if week >= 365:                                   
            i_data_day = 800                           
            week = 0                                  
            index_height += 50                       

fulls()

root.mainloop()#запускаем окно
```

Вот справа в окне появляются плашки, мне нужно чтоб я мог перематывать до самой последней.

Comment: Если "плашки" - это какие-то элементы управления, то прокручивать их можно только расположив на Canvas - по-другому никак.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь прописываем Text

```
textbox = Text(НАСТРОЙКИ)
textbox.pack(НАСТРОЙКИ)
```

А здесь прописываем прокрутку и настраиваем её под Text

```
scroll = Scrollbar(textframe)
scroll.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')
scroll['command'] = textbox.yview
textbox['yscrollcommand'] = scroll.set
```

Answer (score -1):

Здесь нужно отметить скроллер как горизонтальный.
Типа так:

```
scroll_x = tk.Scrollbar(orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
```

Comment: Как это решает проблему, озвученную в вопросе?